# Save endangered parasitic species?

Tags: parasitology, conservation-biology, host-pathogen-interaction

It seems to be an important issue the parasitic control and even some pursue the eradication of some species. Most of the researchers in parasitology are focused on the host damage and population regulation. How do we perceive and value the function of parasites? Is it really needed a change in paradigms and views of dependent species? How important is to conserve them?

Comment: are there any parasites that are endangered of extinction? Even smallpox is extinct only in the wild.

Comment: This is an interesting subject but it sounds like you're focusing on the ethical aspects, which are probably too opinion-based to be a good fit for this site. Can you clarify what you're looking for a bit more?

Answer (score -1):

Although we think of parasites as harmful and tend not to consider them for conservation, they do peform valuable functions including population regulation and the development of immune systems. More philosophically, under the 'intrinsic value' argument sometimes used for conservation, every species should be considered to have an intrinsic right to existence, regardless of its ecosystem function, harmful effects on other species or appeal to humans.

Conveniently, [this](https://www.theguardian.com/science/blog/2017/feb/09/no-wildlife-charity-campaigns-to-save-parasites-but-they-should) article has just been published on this very subject. :)